# Generate a comma separated value using all values from a column in Crystal Report

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a Crystal Report that populates using the data from a Stored Procedure. This Stored Procedure returns 4 rows like so:

OrderNum       Particular
111                    HD
222                    RAM
333                    Charger
444                    Mouse

I want to write a Crystal Report's formula that would display a value like :

111, 222, 333, 444

Also I tried the below formula but since the OrderNum are displayed on different pages, I do not get all the OrderNum values together on the first page :

Shared Stringvar OrderNumList;

OrderNumList:=OrderNumList+{SP.1.OrderNum}+ ", "

Can you please advise on this?

Answer (score 0):

Your formula approach looks correct, except that:

1. if the column is numeric, need to use ToText({SP.1.OrderNum}, 0, "")
2. Use another formula in the section where you wish to display the result. That formula can simply declare the same variable, and return the result of stripping away the last character (the "," at the end.)

Note that there is no need to declare this variable as shared because you are not crossing between a main report and a subreport. It is enough to declare this variable as global.